# get_template_directory() still returning path to previous theme

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress, I've been installing and using various themes, including 2013, Roots, and now BlankSlate. I noticed that now that I've activated BlankSlate, the function `get_template_directory()` used in front-page.php is still returning the path to the Roots theme directory. My current front-page.php looks like this.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section id="content" role="main">
       <img class="frontpageimg" src="<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/images/slogan-2.png">


       <h4>In the Los Angeles area? </h4> <p>Ask about free demo loaners! </p>
       <h4>We also take mail orders.</h4> On all orders, there is a 30-day return policy!</p> 



       <img src = "<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/assets/img/cables-ers-absorber-700.jpg"/></a>
       <img src = "<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/assets/img/blueprint-silencers-v2-700.jpg"/></a>
       <img src = "<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/assets/img/brav-front-page-700.jpg"/></a>

        <a href="contact" class="btn btn-lg btn-orange">Contact Us</a>

</section>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: This really should be a question for the wordpress stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

**Use:**

`<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>`

**Instead of:**

`<?php get_template_directory(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

first of all

1. you can check both theme name is different
2. goto current theme, index page and change template name